# Ages and multiples

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are two tortoises, Tarnell and his grandfather Redoll. Redoll's age is higher than $130$ but less than $170$ and is $15$ times more than Tarnell's age. Later, Redoll's age is $11$ times older than Tarnell's age. How old would Redoll be then?

I started this problem with the fact that "all multiples of 15 end in 5 or 0, just like 5". So I started with the first multiple of $15$ after $130$, $135$. $135/15$= $9$  So when Redoll is 135 years old, Tarnell is 9. So Tarnell and Redoll have $135-9=126$ years apart. But is my reasoning correct? And is there a way I can find out what Redoll's age would be without lots of trial and error?
(I'm only a Year 7, so please explain clearly how you found the solution)

Comment: Does 'Redoll's age is (...) 15 times more than Tarnell's' mean $R=15\cdot T$ or rather $R=T+15\cdot T = 16\cdot T$?

Comment: @CiaPan it means $R= 15 * T$

Comment: This way you should check more numbers, as there are other multiples of 15 in the given range: 150 and 165. You didn't check when Redoll will be 11 times older than Tarnell - and whether the numbers will be integer then. The problem doesnt state they _need_ to be integers, but they _usually_ are, when talking about age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Tarnell's age be $t$ and his grandfather Redoll's age be $r$.
Now, we know $130 \lt r \lt 170$.
Also, $r=15t$.
$\implies r = 135, 150, 165$.
$\implies t = 9, 10, 11$.

Then, after $x$ years,
$r' = r+x$
$t' = t+x$.
Where $r' = 11t'$ , i.e., $r+x=11(t+x)$

Use trial and error method:
If $r = 135$ , $t = 9$ ; $x=3.6$.
If $r = 150$ , $t = 10$ ; $x=4$.
If $r = 165$ , $t = 11$ ; $x=4.4$.

Only $x=4$ is valid as $x$ is number of (whole) years.
Therefore age of Redoll then would be $150+4 = 154$.

Comment: It 15 times more, not 15 times.

Answer (score 0):

Let Tarnell's age is $x$. Then Redoll's age $= x + 15x = 16x$.

So you have to see multiple of $16$ between $130$ and $170$.

We have two cases-

***Case 1-***

Redoll's age $= 144$

Then $x = 9$ $\implies$ Tarnell's age $= 9$

A few years later,

$144+y=11(9+y) \implies 144+y=99+11y$
$$\implies 10y=45 \implies y=\frac92$$

***Case 2-***

Redoll's age $= 160$

Then $x = 10$ $\implies$ Tarnell's age $= 10$

A few years later,

$160+y=11(10+y) \implies 160+y=110+11y$

$$\implies 10y=50 \implies y=5$$

> If we assume that "a few years later" is not a fraction, then ***Case 2*** is your answer.

Comment: that gives 144 or 160. What now?

Comment: its supposed to be $R = 15 * T$

Comment: See this http://www.indiabix.com/aptitude/problems-on-ages/discussion-283

Comment: Also see the explanation below.

Comment: that requires how many years pass before father is 2 1/2 times more than son. In this case, we don't know this piece of information

Comment: Yes I am using y for that.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh The discussion at indiabix.com page it very interesting and enlightening but irrelevant. It explains a proper meaning of the two expressions, but it doesn't decide if OP used appropriate expression. Only [additional question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197999/ages-and-multiples/2199478?noredirect=1#comment4522843_2197999) can make things clear – and it turned out OP meant [R=15×T](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197999/ages-and-multiples/2199478?noredirect=1#comment4524529_2197999).

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh FIY, it's quite a common error in amateur translation e.g. from Slavic languages, where expressions like "n times bigger/longer/deeper/louder/... than x" and "n times less/shorter/... than x" (translated word-by-word here), with n's greater than 1 in both cases, are commonly used for "x times n" and "x divided by n", respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If $R=15\,T$ now, in $x$ years it will be
$$R+x = 11(T+x)$$
so
$$15T+x = 11T+11x$$
which makes
$$4T=10x$$
$$2T=5x$$
If we consider only natural values of all variabes, $x$ must be even: $x=2y$, so
$$T=5y$$
hence
$$R=15T=75y$$
The only multiple of $75$ between $130$ and $170$ is $150$, so
$$R=150$$
$$T=R/15=10$$

Answer: they are $R=150,\ T=10$ y.o. now,  so in $x$ years
$$x=2y = 2(T/5) = 4$$
Redoll will be $154$ years old:
$$\boxed{\color{red}{R+x}} = 150+4 = \boxed{\color{red}{154}} = 11\cdot(10+4) = \color{red}{11\cdot(T+x)}$$

Comment: where'd you get the equation 2x = y from and are my values for t and r correct?

Comment: @bio It's $x=2y$, not $2x=y$. And it follows from $2T=5x$ – the left-hand side $2T$ is even due to $2$ multiplier, so the right-hand side must be even, too. But $5$ is odd, so $x$ must be even, hence there is some $y$ such that $x=2y$.